# How to find data in a text file, and if it doesnt exist, find the closest value

Tags: python

I have a program I am creating to display pixel information of the pixel under my cursor. The program works as expected, but I am having trouble with my next step. I want to take the RGB value of my program and match it to a list of RGB values and colors I have in a text file. I already have the text file open in my program:

```
with open('Color Collection.txt', 'r') as f:
    data=f.read().split('\n')
```

If I wanted to search for a specific value, such as 255, 232, 121, I could us something like:

```
with open('wordlist.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if word in line:
                    print line
```

Then, just use an if statement to match each red green blue value to a value stored in the sheet. My issue is that the sheet doesnt contain all 16 million combinations possible, nor would that be a viable option. I want to do some sort of math function to find the closest value for each RGB value if an exact match does not exist. I am really stuck on how to do this, and any help or pointers on what to do would be greatly appreciated. I am not asking for someone to do the code for me, as this is a school assignment and I want to be able to do it, but if anyone can help guide me it would be GREATLY appreciated :)

thanks!

Comment: You have to define some rules to match the "closest". What is "closest"? SSD on all three components? Ceil/Floor each value to the closest one? Each approach will elect a new "closest one", so you should pick one first, it should get much easier later to determine what to do

Comment: "Fuzzy matching" is usually the paradigm you'd use to do this. [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) is the relevant python library that does that, but I'm not sure if it works on number strings; maybe take the Cartesian Distance between your desired value and each color in your file, and output the minimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take some sample colors you like from the 16 millions, say 1000 colors. put the RGB values for these 1000 color in a matrix, you can use numpy package for this.
you get something like this:

colors = [ [r1, g1, b1], [r2, g2, b2], ... , [r1000, g1000, b1000] ]

also put each color name in a dictionary with the same order you put them in matrix rows, for example:

color_names = {0:'red', 1:'light_red', ...}.

you end up with a matrix of size 1000x3, with each row containing RGB value of one color. you can choose more colors if you like depend on how good your system is.

then when you read the mouse cursor, turn those RGB values to float numbers, and compare how close the color is to each of the 1000 sample colors you chose.

if you use numpy package you can compute euclidean distance very fast like this:

```
import numpy as np

colors = # a matrix of size 1000x3 that you have already filled with 1000 colors.
rgb = # value you read from mouse cursor, for example [200, 100, 120]
distances = np.sqrt( np.sum( np.square(colors - rgb), axis=1 ) )
index_closest = np.argmin(distance)
```

now take the index of the closest color and read it from dictionary.

```
closest_color = color_names[index_closest]
```

you can install numpy package by using : pip install numpy, or conda install numpy

I only wrote the numpy code for calculating distances for you since this is an assignment.
if using numpy seems a bit daunting at first for you, you can forget it and use python lists, but you need to write a for loop and compute distances any way you know.